# how to search for a pair in firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have stored location coordinates in firebase.
I will recieve location periodically from the app.
How can check whether the received data is present in the database?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

as the comment from Itoun already mentioned you should read, how to properly ask.

I will try to help you, based on your given information. If you just want to check, if the data is stored in your Database. Simply go to your firebase console: [Your firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com) go to your Project and check in the Database section if your data is present.

If you want to know how to retrieve data inside your app from any of your firebase db please consider visiting the example site for firebase:
[Example site](https://firebase.google.com/docs/samples/)

There are plenty of examples how to get data from the database for every possible Device.

Comment: i don't want to check manually. i am new to firebase. i am using it as a server. i want some program to check received coordinates present in the DB and if present i want to push notification to the app. please help. thank you

Comment: Thats a bit more of a clarification. You should edit your question in order to be more precise. But as already mentioned if you want to check the database values go to my provided example site and check the Android example. You will most likely finde there an implementation on how to check your data. If not post another more specific question where you actually stuck.